# Only leave longest line when first column is duplicate

Tags: bash, sed, awk, perl

INPUT:

```
user@server:~/bar/foobar$ SAT=$(date -dsaturday +%Y-%m-%d); SUN=$(date -dsunday +%Y-%m-%d)
user@server:~/bar/foobar$ awk 'BEGIN {FS="'^'"} {print $1"\t"$3"\t"$6}' STs.csv STt.csv | egrep -w "${SAT}|${SUN}" | sort -u
'ST30074650'        '2015-10-17 10:00'
'ST30074650'    'someone1@foo.com'  '2015-10-17 10:00'
'ST30085367'    'someone2@foo.com'  '2015-10-18 13:00'
'ST30086369'        '2015-10-17 13:00'
'ST30115016'    'someone3@foo.com'  '2015-10-18 13:00'
'ST30124587'        '2015-10-18 09:00'
'ST30123591'        '2015-10-18 09:00'
user@server:~/bar/foobar$
```

NEEDED OUTPUT:

```
user@server:~/bar/foobar$ SAT=$(date -dsaturday +%Y-%m-%d); SUN=$(date -dsunday +%Y-%m-%d)
user@server:~/bar/foobar$ awk 'BEGIN {FS="'^'"} {print $1"\t"$3"\t"$6}' STs.csv STt.csv | egrep -w "${SAT}|${SUN}" | sort -u | SOMEMAGIC
'ST30074650'    'someone1@foo.com'  '2015-10-17 10:00'
'ST30085367'    'someone2@foo.com'  '2015-10-18 13:00'
'ST30086369'        '2015-10-17 13:00'
'ST30115016'    'someone3@foo.com'  '2015-10-18 13:00'
'ST30124587'        '2015-10-18 09:00'
'ST30123591'        '2015-10-18 09:00'
user@server:~/bar/foobar$
```

**Question**: So if there is a duplicate first column, ex.: "ST30074650" - the longer line should stay only. How could someone do this at the "SOMEMAGIC".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user@machine:~/tmp$ cat f1
'ST30074650'    'someone1@foo.com'  '2015-10-17 10:00'
'ST30085367'    'someone2@foo.com'  '2015-10-18 13:00'
'ST30086369'        '2015-10-17 13:00'
'ST30115016'    'someone3@foo.com'  '2015-10-18 13:00'
'ST30124587'        '2015-10-18 09:00'
'ST30123591'        '2015-10-18 09:00'
'ST30074650'        '2015-10-17 10:00'

user@machine:~/tmp$ sort -r f1 |uniq -w 12 |sort
'ST30074650'    'someone1@foo.com'  '2015-10-17 10:00'
'ST30085367'    'someone2@foo.com'  '2015-10-18 13:00'
'ST30086369'        '2015-10-17 13:00'
'ST30115016'    'someone3@foo.com'  '2015-10-18 13:00'
'ST30123591'        '2015-10-18 09:00'
'ST30124587'        '2015-10-18 09:00'
```

- First sort in reverse order on whole line to get longer lines first
- uniq only checks first 12 characters will retain first (longer) line comparing only 12 chars
- optional final sort to get natural order

Comment: your SOMEMAGIC is better than mine !

Comment: This only works by coincidence on the sample data.  The sort step is not guaranteed to put the longest line first in general, so it is a very fragile solution.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good comment. You are correct. I'm inclined to let the answer stand though, since now we have your caveat, people can read that, and I believe longer line, means lacking email column, and not really length on line. Thank you for good critique.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see what SOMEMAGIC got to do with it

try this awk file

```
{ if ( $1 in a ) {
     if ( length(a[$1]) < length($0)) a[$1]=$0 ;
            } # $1 in a
  else  a[$1]=$0 ; }

END { for ( b in a ) {print a[b] ;}  }
```

use it with (no need for pre sort)

```
... egrep -w "${SAT}|${SUN}" | awk -f u.awk | sort
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -a -e '$line{$F[0]} = $_ if (length($_) > length($line{$F[0]})) ; END { foreach (sort keys %line) { print $line{$_} } };'  STs.csv STt.csv
```

Or, in an easier to read standalone perl script form:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -a

$line{$F[0]} = $_ if (length($_) > length($line{$F[0]})) ;

END {
  foreach (sort keys %line) { print $line{$_} }
};
```

This is essentially the same algorithm as Archemar's answer, but in `perl` rather than `awk`.  In simple terms: using the first field of the input as the key to a hashed array, if the current line of input is longer than what we have stored for the array (defaults to the empty string in perl) then store the current line.    Once we've read all the input (i.e. finished), print out each element of the hash.

Answer (score 0):

refactoring your code (untested due to the lack of raw input data)

```
awk -F '^' -v OFS='\t' \
           -v sat=$(date -d saturday +%F) \
           -v sun=$(date -d sunday +%F) \
'
    $6 !~ "^"sat && $6 !~ "^"sun {next}
    { line = $1 OFS $3 OFS $6 }
    length(line) > lines[$1] {lines[$1] = line}
    END { for (key in lines) print lines[key] }
' STs.csv STt.csv | sort
```

With GNU awk, you can omit the trailing `sort` by using

```
    END { 
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        for (key in lines) print lines[key] 
    }
```